# scrollToPosition method not working when recyclerview is placed inside scrollview/nestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

In my layout, `ScrollView` is the parent and it has `Imageview` (160dp height) and a `Recyclerview` as children. **Scenario:** there's the image and 10 String item list, visible listitems are 0,1,2,3,4. So Whenever there's a new `listitem` ,I will update the list and call `scrollToPosition` method(itemcount -1), but nothing happens. I already have `setNestedScrollEnabled(false)`.

I tried `scrollView.fullScroll(DOWN)` method, `scrollView.scrollTo(0, adapter.itemcount)`, using this it scrolls to last item of the old list, but not scrolled completely to show added new item. This is my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="140dp" />



                <View
                    android:id="@+id/grey_line"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_grey"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/comments_list"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Please help, Thank you!

Comment: Did you got answers for this ques.?? I am also facing same issue... Let me know if you get it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

inside your Layout.

If not then try to use

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focudeableInTouchMode="true"
```

inside your `Recyclerview`

Comment: Didn't work.. I am not using `blocksDescendants` and tried with other two options in recyclerview. no luck